# What does "implicit meaning" means in terms of database design and what should I understand under "DBMS" and DB System Language?

Tags: database, database-design

I have picked up the book named "*Fundamentals of Database Systems, 3rd Edition*" by Elmasri and Navathe to get a basic understanding first. I have started reading it from the first chapter.

> It defines a database and data as "A database is a collection of related data. By data, we mean known facts that can be recorded and that have **implicit** meaning."

What does "implicit meaning" mean here?

> "A database can be created and maintained either by a group of **application programs** written specifically for that task or a **database management system**."

I think application programs are the queries you use to, e.g. , retrieve data or update data etc., aren't they?

What should I envision when I think of a DBMS at its core?

> Examples of updates (like "Change the class of Zarah from Freshman to Sophomore") have been given. Then it goes like,"These informal queries and updates must be **specified** precisely in the **database system language** before **they can be processed**."

What is this Database System Language? Querying Language like SQL, MySQL etc. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does "implicit meaning" mean here

I believe it means that value in a table (say 3395512) doesn't have meaning without knowing what the attribute is, and what relation it is a part of.

> I think application programs are the queries you
> use to, e.g. , retrieve data or update data etc., innit?

Not quite. Applications programs in this context are the applications software developer write to access a database. For example this web site reads and writes to a SQL Server database, or the tools/jobs that that update [data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/).  Compare this to Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS) which is a tool that isn't written for a specific database.

> Can somebody give an example? By example I really mean the simplest
> example of a DBMS on the planet earth (computerized DBMS, and not the
> hand-written file system, ofcourse!)

The term DBMS is typically used to describe products like SQL Server, Oracle, MS Access, MySQL, SQL Lite, etc. Some people also apply the term DBMS to the Admin and Developer tools these products come with.

> What is DB System Language? Querying Language like SQL, MySQL etc. ?

Typically it's some vendor specific implementation of SQL. However many databases also provide APIs that are able to access the database without SQL, although not nearly as popular.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit data means a value of ,any data type, stored in one column and row intersection whose meaning and what that really is can only be understand by relating that value to another value in another column and row intersection on the same row and along with their attributes name.